# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method, get_rec error

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

Below is the code that I'm messing up on. I can provide all my code but everything was working until I inputed this! It's starts at Line 58 , 59 , 60

```
    bd_surface = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Documents/Python/Flappybird   Project/sprites/bluebird-midflap.png').convert
    bd_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bd_surface)
    bd_rect = bd_surface.get_rect(center = (100,512))
```

Here is my whole code just in case

```
import pygame
   import sys


   #Have to define drawing the floor

   def draw_fl():
         screen.blit(fl_surface,(fl_x_pos,900))
         screen.blit(fl_surface,(fl_x_pos + 576,900))
   pygame.init()



       #create display surface x= 560 and 1020 is y
       screen = pygame.display.set_mode((576,1024))
       clock = pygame.time.Clock()

   #Flappy bird Variables

   gravity = .25
   bd_movement = 0

   #background image
   firstpng_surface = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Documents/Python /Flappybird Project/sprites/background-day.png').convert()
   firstpng_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(firstpng_surface).convert()


   fl_surface= pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Documents/Python/Flappybird    Project/sprites/base.png').convert()
   fl_surface= pygame.transform.scale2x(fl_surface)

   #floor x position
   fl_x_pos = 0



   bd_surface = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Documents/Python/Flappybird    Project/sprites/bluebird-midflap.png').convert
   bd_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bd_surface)
   bd_rect = bd_surface.get_rect(center = (100,512))

    while True:
     
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             sys.exit()
      
              
              
    #==moving the floor surface forward want to move it to the left
    screen.blit(firstpng_surface,(0,0))
    

    screen.blit(bd_surface,bd_rect)
    fl_x_pos -=1
    draw_fl()
    if fl_x_pos <= -576:
        fl_x_pos = 0
        
 
    #draws on screen
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

ERROR MESSAGE
line 59, in 
bd_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(bd_surface)

TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not builtin_function_or_method

Comment: It's a typo. You missed the parenthesis (`()`) at the end of `bd_surface = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Documents/Python/Flappybird    Project/sprites/bluebird-midflap.png').convert`

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. You missed the parenthesis (`()`) at the end of:

<s>`bd_surface = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Documents/Python/Flappybird    Project/sprites/bluebird-midflap.png').convert`</s>

```py
bd_surface = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Documents/Python/Flappybird    Project/sprites/bluebird-midflap.png').convert()
```